# How do I stop Bootstrap Input Boxes and Buttons from overlapping the header and footer of a page when scrolling?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The issue I am having is that on a basic auction web page (This page is made for show at this point and is not intended to have a functioning auction system as of yet), the input boxes and buttons underneath the individual sculptures overlap the header/footer when the page is scrolled. This page is designed with a mobile UI, hence the navigation icons in the footer and when the page is displayed on mobile is when the overlapping will become a problem, due to the need for scrolling.

How would I fix this?

```
        <title>Sculpture at Doddington</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">

        <div class="header">
            <br>
            <img src="/img/hall.png" class="mainlogo">
            <h1 style="font-family: 'bebas' !important;">Sculpture at Doddington</h1>
            <h2 style="font-family: 'bebas' !important;">July 30th - September 11th</h2>
            <br>
        </div>

        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div class="content">

            <div class="exhibit-frame">

                <center><img src="/img/daisies.jpg" class="exhibit-image"></center>
                <br>
                <span class="exhibit-title">Daisies</span><br><br>
                <span class="exhibit-number">Number: 1</span><br>
                <span class="exhibit-artist">Artist: Lynn Baker</span><br>
                <span class="exhibit-material">Material: Kiln Formed Glass</span><br><br>
                <div class="row">  
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="input-group formgroup1">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control input1" placeholder="£">
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn-sm btn-warning">Bid</button>
                      </span>
                    </div><!-- /input-group -->
                  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
                <br><br>
                <hr class="featurette-divider">
                <br>

            </div>

            <div class="exhibit-frame">

                <center><img src="/img/daisies.jpg" class="exhibit-image"></center>
                <br>
                <span class="exhibit-title">Daisies</span><br><br>
                <span class="exhibit-number">Number: 1</span><br>
                <span class="exhibit-artist">Artist: Lynn Baker</span><br>
                <span class="exhibit-material">Material: Kiln Formed Glass</span><br><br>
                <form>
                    <img src="/img/nocaptcha.gif">
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="input-group">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control bid_amount" placeholder="£">
                       <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn-sm btn-warning auction_bid_button" type="button">Bid</button>
                       </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <br><br>
                <hr class="featurette-divider">
                <br>

            </div>

        </div> <!-- Content Div -->

        <footer class="footer">
            <p class="buttons">
                    <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home icon1"></i></a>
                    <a href="/gardens"><i class="fa fa-map-marker icon2"></i></a>
                    <a href="/directory"><i class="fa fa-book icon3"></i></a>
            </p>            
        </footer>

    </div>

</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/iamjawa/u4cv31us/ 
- Current Code (Some of the CSS is for other pages on the site and will not be relevant for this page)

Comment: Thanks for your help - I've updated the jsfiddle with z-index changes but still having issues with the input box overlapping - What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you need to set `z-index` in header and footer div like this

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4F7776;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:9;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 8%;
    background-color: #4F7776;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
  z-index:9;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/u4cv31us/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Just for educational purposes, any reason why a z index of 9 works but a z index of 2 didn't?

Comment: what is the z-index of button which were overlapping?

Comment: I didn't set one in the CSS so I'm guessing that Bootstrap sets a z index value for their elements?

Comment: check in bootstrap.css on `.input-group .form-control` there is a css `z-index:2`. So you can also apply `z-index:3` to header and footer